# What is this pattern in this calculation using primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

So I was bored and when I get bored I write small programs that calculate something. This time I did this:

1. I searched for the amount of primes bellow 10,000,000 using Sieve of Eratosthenes starting at k = 2 (as you would normally)
2. Again I searched for the amount of primes bellow 10,000,000 but this time starting Sieve of Eratosthenes at k = k + 1 (so at the first step you start at 3 so now every number that is divisible only by 1, itself and now 2 is a "prime")
3. Repeat step 2 10,000 times
4. Print out the differences of the number of primes between each step.

And now we get this http://pastebin.com/PYf1jctv

Putting those numbers in a image we get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHmhH.png

[image]

This looked pretty interesting to me so I did some further testing. First off the sequence of each number seems to follow a unique pattern and it never changes.

1. Every second number is a 1, so each time we take away the numbers 2,4,6... only those are actually added as the new primes in which case the number of primes only increases by 1.
2. The twos are always 5 numbers apart
3. Here things start getting different the threes follow a 19, 9 pattern
4. The fours are in a 41, 27, 13, 27, 13, 27, 41, 13 pattern (this again repeats forever as it seems)
5. The fives are a 49 number sequence already.

These sequences seem to go on for every number, another interesting thing about those sequences after 3 is that they seem to be in 2 parts the first part is a really long palindrome and the second part is one number and then again the palindrome repeats.

My understanding also is that at the part where the "graph" starts to fall off the numbers start getting incorrect because 10,000,000 is too small at that point, as they should continue to rise. But this already took like 1 hour to calculate.

Another interesting thing is that if we take away all the ones, twos etc we get a nice pyramid that always increases by 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/igw8h.png

[image]

So why does this work like this?

Comment: Is this not [A055396](http://oeis.org/A055396) in OEIS?

Comment: yea i am asking if this has a name

Comment: Do you mean this : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSpiral.html ?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is the prime numbers. All numbers in the pyramid are results of the prime numbers. When k increases all numbers all still sieved up to the square of k. All composites below $k^2$ are combinations of smaller numbers and a larger prime. When a prime is sieved all these results are sieved in one increase of resulting in the pattern you described.